# Ajax function not calling php script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajax

So I'm making a Image gallery site, and I have a bunch of buttons such as approve image, and download image, which call the JS function "runAJAX" and based on the request type, the php is supposed to prefore a specific task. The issue I'm having is that the AJAX function is saying it's successfully run, but the php file is not being run. When I run it, "Request Completed" prints but no txt file is created like it supposed to. Any help would be greatly appreceated. Thank you very much.

```
// imageID is an int of the image UID
// request is a string that describes the button (approve, download etc.) 
function runAJAX(imageID, request) {

    // myArr is a JSON array
    var myArr = allJSON;
    console.log("UID is" + imageID);

    for (var i = 0; i < myArr.length; i++){
        if (myArr[i].UID == imageID){
            switch (request) {
                case "approve": myArr[i].approved = "true"; console.log("Approve was set to true"); break;
                case "download": console.log("Image will be downloaded"); break; 
                default: console.log("No action will be done for this request"); 
            } // switch
        } // if
    } // for

    $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: 'requestAJAX.php',
            data: {request: request, newJSON: JSON.stringify(myArr), download: imageID},
        success: function(){
            console.log("Request Completed: " + request);
            window.location.reload(false); 
        } // success   
    }); 
} // runAJAX
```

requestAJAX.php

```
<?php

switch ($_POST["request"]) {
    case "approve":
        // output to checking to see what the request is
        touch("AJAXtest.txt");
        file_put_contents("AJAXtest.txt", $_POST["request"]);
        unlink("test.json");
        $stringyJSON = json_decode($_POST["newJSON"], true);
        $finalJSON = json_encode($stringyJSON, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
        $file = "galleryinfo.json";
        touch($file);
        file_put_contents($file, $finalJSON);
        break; 
    case "download":
        // output for checking to see what the request is
        touch("AJAXtest.txt");
        file_put_contents("AJAXtest.txt", $_POST["request"]);

        // Get parameters
        $file = $_POST["download"]; 
        $filepath = "UploadedImages/" . $file;

        if(file_exists($filepath)) {
            header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
            header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
            header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($filepath).'"');
            header('Expires: 0');
            header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
            header('Pragma: public');
            header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($filepath));
            flush(); // Flush system output buffer
            readfile($filepath);
            exit;
        } // if
        break: 
    default: 
        // output for checking to see what the request is
        touch("AJAXtest.txt");
        file_put_contents("AJAXtest.txt", "No request made");
        echo "No request was made"; 
}
?>
```

Comment: Not creating the file is not the same as the PHP script not running at all. Your first job is to find out which one of those it actually is. Have you tried to debug the AJAX request all, using your browser's Developer Tools? have you got error logging switched on on the PHP side?

Comment: P.S. As a separate point, downloading files via AJAX won't work. The data just ends up inside a variable in your JavaScript code. It won't generate a file download like a regular HTTP request can.

Comment: Are you sure that you are passing the right values in the functions `request` parameter `runAJAX(imageID, request) `

Comment: @ADyson Thanks for your response :) I haven't been using any dev tools but that's definatly something I'll look into. Also, I'm downloading with the php not the ajax, but thanks for letting me know, it definatly helps to know that if I run into any issues down the road.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I did a ton of tests and printed those values, and yeah, they are always what they're supposed to be...

Comment: "I'm downloading with the php not the ajax"...that doesn't really make sense. PHP, running on the server, delivers the file data in response to an incoming request, but if that request is generated via AJAX on the client-side (which, according to your code, is the case here), then that file data is returned to the JavaScript code which initiated the AJAX request, and so it will not initiate a file download. Whereas if the request was initiated by clicking a link, or typing in the address bar, to generate a non-AJAX request, then the browser would receive the file data directly and download it.